# What does that mean by being less than infinity?

Tags: calculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

One of the most immediate qualitative inferences from Cauchy's inequality is the simple fact that

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2 < \infty.  and.  \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2 < \infty$

imply that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_kb_k| < \infty$

I found this assumption from my Math book and I wonder if being less than infinity means being finite or not.

Comment: Yes, it means it converges to a "finite" value, i.e., to a real number.

Comment: Since we have only non-negative summands this is here equivalent to being convergent (finite sums).

Comment: thank you guys, I really appreciate it

Comment: "less than infinite" is usually meant to mean simply finite.  Although I suppose it could technically mean "finite OR negaitive infinity".  As $-\infty$ is clearly not an option "$<\infty$" can be thought of as simply notation for "finite".

Comment: Note, the condition $< \infty$ should only be used where the terms are nonnegative.  Otherwise write out "converges" instead.